# Date command go back to 30 days from a particular date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, epoch

```
 ADate=`date -d"10 days ago" +%s` 
 BDate=`date -d"$BDate - 30 days" +%s`
```

It is throwing error as invalid date.

Comment: Doesnt work on SLES 12 SP1...

Comment: You are trying to set BDate to be 30 days before BDate.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
ADate=`date -d"10 days ago"` 
BDate=`date -d"$ADate - 30 days" +%s`
echo $BDate
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
ADate=$(date -d"10 days ago" +Y%-%m-%d")
BDate=$(date -d"$ADate - 30 days" +%s)
echo $BDate
```

Output: 1453417200